# Verification error on adobe using pdftron sample

Tags: pdftron

If you run the PDFTron Digital Signature Sample that is in the node-js library. You get a sample document that works on FoxIT Reader for validation, but will throw an error on Adobe. This is what Adobe gives me. It also doesn't allow for me to validate it in Adobe reader with that issue. This is in the default certification sample, we're looking for a work around to get it to work with most major PDF readers not just foxit. Any clues anyone?

```
Error during signature verification.  

The format of this signature is not supported by this signature method. You may require a newer version of the signature handler.
```

This is the sample code: https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/nodejs/guides/features/signature/certify-pdf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for letting us know about this. I believe you are hitting a typo that is in that sample.

Please change the following line from

```
sigDict.putName('SubFilter', 'adbe.pkcs7,detached');
```

to

```
sigDict.putName('SubFilter', 'adbe.pkcs7.detached');
```

Note the comma should be a period before the word `detached`.

The typo will be fixed shortly.

Also, note that new API is coming to our NodeJS API. Here is how that sample will look soon.
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/linux/guides/features/signature/certify-pdf

Comment: That worked for us, thanks! The only other thing I would suggest in the API docs is the ability to add a date to the certificate. We are using this line here sigDict.PutString("M", "D:20130417092950-07'00'"); But it was hard to find out how to do that from the samples and docs.